# Squid proxy does not consider localhost traffic

Tags: proxy, logging, squid, localhost, google

I installed `squid` on `Kali` linux, configured my browser to send whole traffic through `squid`. However, `squid` doesn't consider `localhost` traffic. Actually, I run this command to check log file while I'm browsing:

```
tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log
```

It considers all traffics except `localhost` one, and when I go to `localhost` in my browser, the below line is submitted in the log file by `squid`:

```
127.0.0.1 TCP_TUNNEL/200 39 CONNECT www.google.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.21.196
```

I don't know why it submits `google` when I go to `localhost`. I configured `squid` using [Install Squid](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_17.04&p=squid&f=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should configure your browser correctly, if you use `firefox`, simply go to `Options --> General --> Network Proxy --> Settings` , and in the `No Proxy for` section, clear `localhost, 127.0.0.1`.